# Apache Rewrite Regex conditionally appending a substring to the replacement?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, conditional-statements

Hi :) There's no better way to explain this one than by example.

### USUAL CASE

I use this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)(\?.+)?$ index.php?params=$1 [L]
```

To do something like:

```
# abc.com/home      =>      abc.com/index.php?params=home
```

However, this discards any preexisting GET parameters, so with:

```
http://localhost/ajax/workouts/getExerciseDetails?exerciseID=41
```

I get:

```
params=ajax/workouts/getExerciseDetails
```

When I need:

```
params=ajax/workouts/getExerciseDetails&exerciseID=41
```

SO... My question in English is: Is there a way to conditionally append any preexisting GET params (aka the string after the '?') to the replacement AND still satisfy my main use of this regex?

If this cannot be done in the same rewrite rule, perhaps by using an if/then/else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) to get the original query automatically appended to the new:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?params=$1 [L,QSA]
```